# Android jquery ajax error length required

Tags: jquery, android

I have a piece of code that works on most browsers except the Android browser.  On Android if throws the following error: "Length Required"

Android OS: 2.2
jQuery: 1.5.1

```
$.ajax({
    type: "put",
    url: '/offers/' + offer.offer_data.id + '/delete_active',
    success: function(){
      alert('success');         
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dummy parameter data fixed the issue.  Found the answer in this post http://weblogs.asp.net/gabriellopez/archive/2010/03/12/jquery-web-service-invocation-411-length-required-error.aspx

```
$.ajax({
    type: "put",
    url: '/offers/' + offer.offer_data.id + '/delete_active',
    data: "{ blank:'blank' }",
    success: function(){
      alert('success');         
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `data` line as i see it is not needed in your request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "put",
    url: '/offers/' + offer.offer_data.id + '/delete_active',
    success: function(){
      alert('success');         
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried that. No luck.  I'll remove that part from the code still.